# Could muting the system volume cause coreadiuod to use lots of CPU?

Tags: cocoa, macos, core-audio

I mute and later unmute the OS X system volume with the following code:

```
void SetMute(AudioDeviceID device, BOOL mute)
{
    UInt32 muteVal = (UInt32)mute;

    AudioObjectPropertyAddress address = {
        kAudioDevicePropertyMute,
        kAudioDevicePropertyScopeOutput,
        0
    };

    OSStatus err;
    err = AudioObjectSetPropertyData(device,
                                     &address,
                                     0,
                                     NULL,
                                     sizeof(UInt32),
                                     &muteVal);
    if (err)
    {
        NSString * message;
        /* big switch statement on err to set message */
        NSLog(@"error while %@muting: %@", (mute ? @"" : @"un"), message);
    }
}
```

The value of `device` is determined with

```
AudioDeviceID GetDefaultAudioDevice()
{
    OSStatus err;
    AudioDeviceID device = 0;
    UInt32 size = sizeof(AudioDeviceID);
    AudioObjectPropertyAddress address = {
        kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultOutputDevice,
        kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal,
        kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster
    };

    err = AudioObjectGetPropertyData(kAudioObjectSystemObject,
                                     &address,
                                     0,
                                     NULL,
                                     &size,
                                     &device);
    if (err)
    {
        NSLog(@"could not get default audio output device");
    }

    return device;
}
```

And I also check whether the system volume is currently muted, with:

```
BOOL GetMute(AudioDeviceID device)
{
    UInt32 size = sizeof(UInt32);
    UInt32 muteVal;

    AudioObjectPropertyAddress address = {
        kAudioDevicePropertyMute,
        kAudioDevicePropertyScopeOutput,
        0
    };

    OSStatus err;
    err = AudioObjectGetPropertyData(device,
                                     &address,
                                     0,
                                     NULL,
                                     &size,
                                     &muteVal);
    if (err)
    {
        NSString * message;
        /* big switch to set message */
        NSLog(@"error while getting mute status: %@", message);
    }

    return (BOOL)muteVal;
}
```

All of this seems to work fine -- the system mutes and unmutes with the same behavior as if the user hit the mute key on the keyboard (unmuting restores the last volume set before muting, etc).

I have noticed that at some unspecified time after my program does this, `coreaudiod` begins to consume a lot more CPU than normal (in my case, this is only around 5-7%, but ordinarily it reports 0.0% in Activity Monitor). As far as I can tell, I'm using the Core Audio APIs correctly there, and nothing looks like it should be causing any glitches in `coreaudiod`, so I'm hoping that someone can either point out an issue with my code, or point me towards what else (possibly unrelated?) might be causing the CPU usage in `coreaudiod`. I should also note that when I observe `coreaudiod` using more CPU than normal, there's no sound playing, and the system is unmuted.

Comment: There's been issues for some time with coreaudio using CPU (e.g. http://discussions.info.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2054197&start=15&tstart=45). Surely you are getting closer to the cause!

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if some other habit of my usage is causing this, rather than my program. Thanks for the link.